# How can I return a valid Json object from a PHP file to a jQuery file

Tags: php, ajax, json, jquery, jsonp

I made the simplest senario possible to make sure I didn't make a stupid mistake

**The HTML/JS file** (using jQuery 1.6.x but I also tried it on jsfiddle with 1.9.x

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: 'http://example.com/api/test.php',
    success: function(data){
        //Never reached
        alert('Success');
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

**test.php** - PHP 5.3.x

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8", true);
echo json_encode(array("test" => "test"));
?>
```

**Error returned**

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

I've messed with the php file's header and some parameters in the ajax call. Nothing worked. I'm really confused as to why this simple scenario does not work. The problem is on the PHP side because changing the url to a different source (http://echo.jsontest.com/test/test for example) works. I have a feeling it's a PHP config but I dont know where to look.

Comment: Are you getting the correct response when opening the url directly with your browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `application/json` as the content type for JSONP.  Instead, use `application/javascript`.  This is not really necessary, but a JSONP response should be valid JavaScript and a bare word object is not hence the syntax error.  You need to do something like this:

```
// JS
url: "http://example.com/api/text.php?callback=?"

//php
echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . json_encode(array("test" => "test")) . ')';
```

More information about JSONP via jQuery is available in [the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Oh... Right... Those ASP.NET MVC jQuery helpers really makes you dumb after using them for too long! :) Thank you, that was it.